# How good is this svn structure?

Tags: svn

[image]

Above is the mock of structure I plan to use for java projects in my organization. What do you guys think about it? Does it look conventional? Also, if you take project1, under tags, you can see, 1.0.1, 1.0.2 and so on - these are release tags, created post release. Now, what kind of tags would exist under Dev branch? When would they be created? Should I create branches under DevBranch for each developer? I am confused.

Comment: So you have branches that have branches? And a new trunk that resides under the `Dev` branch? If you were using Maven for example, how would you do the releases with this branches in branches model?

Comment: @RedFilter yes, it is all in one repo. Inspired by http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/

Comment: @maba I am not sure how I would do a release using maven. I would appreciate your suggestions in this context.

Comment: As the projects grow over time it's easier to maintain an individual repository per project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest either this:

```
repo--tags
    --branches
    --trunk--project1
           --project2
           --project3
```

...if you want to tag and branch all projects simultaneously

Or this:

```
repo--project1--tags
              --branches
              --trunk
    --project2--tags
              --branches
              --trunk
    --project3--tags
              --branches
              --trunk
```

..if you want to be able to do tagging and branching separately for each project.

Don't nest tags/branches/trunks, it does not make sense conceptually.

A branch pertains to a development cycle (i.e. myproject_1_1_sprint_1), a tag marks the state of the project at a given point in time (i.e. myproject_1_1_RC03, meaning release candidate 3 of version 1.1). Note that these are purely conceptual differences determined by convention. There is no technical difference in SVN between branches and tags, they are both so called '[cheap copies](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s02.html#svn-ch-4-dia-3)' of the project's directory structure.

See [this excellent article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) describing a successful branching strategy for GIT, which is also applicable to other versioning systems like SVN.

Answer (score 5):

**What do you guys think about it?**

Not OK. Usually, `branches` **does not** contain further `tags`, `trunk`, `branches`. `Branch` is like `trunk` but a parallel development stream. Usually, you create a branch by `copy`ing from `trunk` or from `tag` or from another `branch`. Apart from that it's OK.

**Does it look conventional?**

Yes, it is.

**Now, what kind of tags would exist under Dev branch?**

By tags you mean names. You can give them a little descriptive names.. like or `project1_new_caching_mechanism` or `project1_1.1_spot_fixes` -- indicating this is probably copied from release `1.1` tag to fix some of the issues in the release. When you release this branch, you will like to merge these fixes to other parallel running branches and trunk.

**When would they be created?**

Whenever you find parallel development scenario. Like you wanted to improve the performance by load testing and adding improved code to it without hampering the main development branch. Or for spot fixes. Or for feature replacement.. or for multiple version support.

**Should I create branches under DevBranch for each developer?**

**No.** SVN is centralized repository... (unlike Git), the purpose of any SCM is to allow multiple devs to work on it simultaneously... you will be defying the purpose by separating repos for each dev.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not completly wrong I think below Dev (and Experimental), there should be no branches/tags/trunks. If you want to create a release of the dev branch, you would put it here:

```
/svn/projects/project1/tags/dev-1.0.1
```

or something like that. E.g. Dev and Experimental are like the trunk folder of each branch. If you want to make a branch from Dev you could call it Dev2 but I suppose that is making it more complicated than required.

Also I would not use Dev at all but rather do everything that belongs to the Dev branch in the trunk

```
/svn/projects/project1/trunk
```

but there may be a good reason to have an additional Dev branch.

Comment: are you suggesting that I should do changes on trunk and not on dev branch?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. I would add `test` too if you need to automate it with Maven or Ivy.

Comment: Why would you need a `test` folder when running tests? Should the test results be version controlled?

Comment: @maba he means like this /svn/projects/project1/trunk/test and accordingly in the branches. So the tests are not in the src folders.

Comment: @kw4nta Well maybe. I guess I am too buried in using maven and its structures where the test code actually belongs to the source code. It just doesn't get put in the released jars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [SVNBook (Version Control with Subversion)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  I don't think tags belong there.

I don't like your Dev, Experimental, etc.  Those are what /branches are about.  When you're done, you either merge them to /trunk or just hang onto the branches.

Tags are for when you go to production and you want to create a read-only, never to be modified copy of the branch you released.

You have choices for arranging the repository:

1. One repository with /trunk, /branches, and /tags underneath it, and projects under those.
2. One repository with multiple projects underneath it, each with its own /trunk, /branches, and /tags underneath.
3. One repository per project, each with its own /trunk, /branches, and /tags.

Comment: Belongs where? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.tags

Comment: @duffymo yep, I removed my comment. A little further reading on the link that maba had shared - I can see some good examples.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to have "branches per feature" where each feature or developer has its own branch which gets promoted to trunk where the feature is done. if so, you may want to take a look at a distributed version control system like mercurial or git.

If you want to use svn (and you may have good reasons), then I suggest to have two different `branch` directories: a `dev-branches` for branches created for features, developers or proofs of concepts, and `branches` for the branching of the production code (to be able to fix bugs in production while still on development), and scratch both `Experimental` and `Dev`

Comment: what if I wanted vendor specific branches? Again, with dev-branches, are you saying that I should create tags,branches,trunk under dev-branches?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to use branches for ongoing work for tag numbers, an tags for static snapshots.  That way, when it is time to feature freeze the release of `1.0.1`, I copy the trunk into `branches\1.0.1` and as I build releases during final stabilization / bug fixes, I make non-editable copies in `tags\1.0.1.5`, `tags\1.0.1.11`, etc.

The key is to make a quick script that checks if the parent directory is a `tags` directory, and then to reconfigure the sub-directory to have no write access just after it is created.  Otherwise, your tags are moving tags, and that defeats the purpose of static tagging.

Comment: another question in this context would be.. how often should I release and tag? In general, for any random project, how long would it take to change from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2? one day? one week? How do I plan for releases and versioning?

Comment: It doesn't matter how long to release and tag, feature freeze _must_ be before stabilization, unless you have coders who actually write bug-free software that can withstand testing on the first go; or, you hold back on all main branch development when attempting to get a release out the door.  Neither option is feasible or optimal, hence the working release branch.  "Experimental", "Dev", "Client-1" branches, etc are all what the branch is for, not it's name; which is a mistake IMHO.  What happens is branch clutter, which will occur (with your second "experiment", client, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify what you have.  The "DEV" should be your trunk.  You should start with your project level, and each project should have a tags, trunk and branches directory.

```
projects/<project>
    tags
    trunk
    branches
```

If you need something like "Experimenal" and "Client-1" as you put above, it's should be a branch based on trunk

```
projects/<project>/branches/experimental
projects/<project>/branches/client-1
```

Likewise, tags should be in a common place, and you can use folders to organize them:

```
projects/<project>/tags/experimental
projects/<project>/tags/client-1
```

There's a lot of reasons for this

1. Predictability for the user ==> someone should be able to predict your svn
   structure no matter which module they are in.
2. Predictability for hooks ==> Your hooks which keep tags read only
   really need a predictable structure in order to avoid being
   excessively complicated.
3. Merging ==> your "experimental" and
   "client-1" branches should be branched off your trunk so that it's
   easy to consistently merge trunk features down to those branches. 
   Likewise, you can merge features up as well so long as they have
   branched from trunk.

And i'm sure there's a lot more, but these are the ones that pop right out at me.

Comment: but, aren't tags supposed to be different from branches? Branches are supposed to be friendly names and tags are supposed to reflect your release numbers?

Comment: Tags and branches are identical from an svn perspective.  They are simply a lightweight copy of a path at a particular revision number.  What makes them different is that repositories typically have commit hooks that prevent you from actually modifying anything inside an existing tag.  If your tag paths are not predictable, this is rather annoying to do (and searching for /tags/ anywhere in the url is not a good idea, as that might match code directories)